# When using PM2 to debug Node.js, is there a CLI option to avoid a command prompt opening for every thread using the cluster module?

Tags: pm2

I'm using node.js's cluster module to fork 16 threads to fully leverage my i9 9900k with a node.js program. I need to debug memory leaks and PM2 seems to offer the best analysis capabilities of a Node.js program that I've been able to find, but when I run the program with PM2, it opens an additional command prompt for every thread forked and 16 windows popping up in my face every time I run it isnt optimal. Is there a CLI option for PM2 to avoid this?

A quick google didn't turn anything up but sometimes you gurus know a thing or two google doesn't.

Comment: Quick answer - no. Why can't you debug the problem without pm2?

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov My event loop is slowing down when processing and accumulating large (GB+) data sets in memory and I realize the large data structures are the likely culprit, read / write times to and from memory seem to slow down with bigger objects in JS, but I'm not sure exactly what's going on and I was looking for a profiler. I looked into tools to do analysis with: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/diagnostics-flamegraph/ But the 0x module doesn't support clustering and I'm on Windows so that cuts out a few *Nix only tools.

Comment: You are right, but pm2 is unnecessary for debugging these problems. Running one process without pm2 and collecting memory snapshots should be enough to see the relative usage and find out what exactly consumes the memory. You don't need to have 16 processes to find out what consumes the memory.

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov If only it were so easy. Since I've been leveraging 16 threads, my program is set up at it's core with a messaging system between workers to accomplish all of its tasks and eliminating threading for testing would in itself be quite a challenge. I think my best solution might be to expand on a monitor.watch(myObjectName) module I've created that reports major size increases to objects, so that it also tracks how long it takes to read from or write to these objects over time.

Comment: You can implement a script that will make a lot of messages to your workers. Run one worker without pm2 and run another script that will start spawning a lot of messages to your single process.

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov perhaps this is the true solution here: https://v8.dev/blog/hash-code . Afterall, if I'm indeed working with "big" data and my code already runs as optimally as it can, with the only issue being the necessary object size as opposed to memory leaks, the only solution would seem to be improving the technology I'm using to read/write that big data in some way. JavaScript does not seem to use hash tables behind the scenes in normal object structures, as that would imply O(n) time complexity on access, which we obviously dont enjoy in JS

Comment: And how an article about JavaScript engine solves your pm2 related problem?

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov see edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213542/discussion-between-eugene-obrezkov-and-viziionary).

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer - no. You can not set the behaviour you want through PM2 options (*at least I couldn't manage to find it as well*).

Though, if you ask me. I think it is not a great way to look for some memory leaks by introducing more entropy in your debug setup. Make a minimal reproducible example with one Node.js script, that will have those memory leaks and use available tooling to gather snapshots, where you will find relative changes to the memory consumption which leads you to the solution.

There are a lot of articles out there, like:

- [Finding And Fixing Node.js Memory Leaks: A Practical Guide](https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/04/03/how-to-track-and-fix-memory-leak-with-nodejs.html)
- [Memory Leaks Demystified](https://nodesource.com/blog/memory-leaks-demystified)

Well, you got the idea. Hope it helps you find a leak.